# Filter null properties from list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, methods

I have a method that accepts a variable that has a list of properties connected to it. What I need to do is create a linq query that will flag the current variable coming in as missing an "address" and add it to a list.

```
    public void Teachers(List<Teacher> teachers)
    {
        foreach (Name name in teachers)
        {
            int age = program.CalculateAge(name.BirthDate.Year);

            Name address = FilterAddress(name);

            // Output Teachers Name - First Name, Last Name
            if (name.Type.Equals(Name.NameType.Teacher))
            {
                OutputToConsole(name.FirstName, name.LastName, age);
                program.WriteAddress(name);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Above is the method that will add the current variable in foreach loop to the FilterAddress Method. Below is where the variable is being passed. This variable has a List property named "Address" that is connected to it. This address can be null. I need to select each name with an address of null and add it to a list. But as you guessed, my LINQ code below doesn't work and just breaks.

```
    public Name FilterAddress(Name name)
    {
        var NullItems = name.Select(x => x.Addresses).OfType<Name>();

        return NullItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public Name[] FilterAddress(Name name)
    {
        return name.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Addresses))
                                .Select(x => x.Name)
                                .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: @Travis that's another question ,create a new one.

Answer (score -3):

Only need to add the "if null" check in the query to return if Adresses is null.

```
var NullItems = name.Where(x => x.Addresses == null);
```

Comment: that will definitely not compile